# Can I make this amp meter work with a hot water heater?

Tags: water-heater

I currently use a clamp meter around one of the hot legs going to the hot water heater to check amps. What I would really like is a meter that stays on all the time so I can monitor the meter 24/7. It needs to be placed approximately 6 feet from the hot water heater and would need to stay on all the time (in other words not time out so the numbers are not readable).

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help,
Yeto

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're playing with fire here. That device is an unlisted component. Leaving it plugged in all the time with nobody watching it is risky at best.

That being said, there are plenty of reputable clamp meters and current monitoring devices available. So in general:

- A 240V hot water heater doesn't use neutral. It just uses two hots.
- To measure current on a 240V/120V circuit (e.g., oven or clothes dryer or an entire panel) you need to monitor both hot wires. You don't need to monitor neutral because that is simply the difference between the hots.
- To measure current on a pure 240V circuit (e.g., water heater) you only need to monitor *one* of the two hot wires as the other will be identical.
- I would not recommend powering a monitor like this from the lines feeding the device being monitored - for a bunch of reasons. So a separate set of wires to plug in to standard 120V power is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

amazon, $20

> CrocSee AC 80-260V 100A CRS-022B LCD Display Digital Current Voltage Power Energy Frequency Power Factor Multimeter Ammeter Voltmeter with 100A Split Core Current Transformer

you want any *panel amp meter* using a current transformer, for doing 240VAC.  There are numerous available from many different places.  Using a split core current transformer makes installation easy.

I recommend powering the amp meter from the lines feeding the water heater, for a bunch of reasons.

remembered the *good* panel meter, check out : https://www.trumeter.com/products/

Comment: That's more like - UL listed!

Comment: thinking because something's UL listed won't catch fire is like thinking because your car has a 5-star crash safety rating you won't get injured in an accident, or like something that's FDA approved is healthy for you and won't harm you.

Comment: not a guarantee. But it helps increase the odds.